# Proving that $\{x \in \mathbb{C}: 2<\mathfrak{Re}(x)<5\}$ is an open subset

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, complex-numbers

I am studying Conway's Function of One Complex Variable and have currently reached the topic of open and closed subsets. I have made up my own exercise: Prove that $\{x \in \mathbb{C}: 2<\mathfrak{Re}(x)<5\}$ is an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ under the Euclidean metric. I don't know exactly where my proof goes wrong, but I know it to be incorrect.

Firstly, $G$ is indeed a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ just by construction.
Now, pick $x \in G$ arbitrarily meaning $2<\mathfrak{Re}(x)<5$. We want to show that there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that the open ball $B\left(x;\epsilon\right)=\{y \in \mathbf{C}: d\left(x,y\right)<\epsilon\}$ is entirely contained in $G$. Let $\epsilon = \text{min}\{\mathfrak{Re}(x)-2, 5-\mathfrak{Re}(x)\}$. Now, take any $y \in B\left(x;\epsilon\right)$

\begin{align*}
&\implies \sqrt{\left(\mathfrak{Re}y-\mathfrak{Re}x\right)^2+\left(\mathfrak{Im}y-\mathfrak{Im}x\right)^2}<\text{min}\{\mathfrak{Re}x-2, 5-\mathfrak{Re}x\}\\
&\implies \left(\mathfrak{Re}y-\mathfrak{Re}x\right)^2+\left(\mathfrak{Im}y-\mathfrak{Im}x\right)^2<\text{min}\{\left(\mathfrak{Re}x-2\right)^2, \left(5-\mathfrak{Re}x\right)^2\}\\
&\implies \left(\mathfrak{Re}y-\mathfrak{Re}x\right)^2 < \text{min}\{\left(\mathfrak{Re}x-2\right)^2, \left(5-\mathfrak{Re}x\right)^2\}\\
&\implies \text{min}\{-\mathfrak{Re}x+2, -5+\mathfrak{Re}x\}< \mathfrak{Re}y-\mathfrak{Re}x < \text{min}\{\mathfrak{Re}x-2, 5-\mathfrak{Re}x\}\\
&\implies \text{min}\{2, -5+2\mathfrak{Re}x\}< \mathfrak{Re}y < \text{min}\{2\mathfrak{Re}x-2, 5\}\\
\end{align*}

Here, there must be an error. As in worst case, the left side of the last equation is $-5$.

My only guess as to where I went wrong is that my algebra regarding how $\text{min}$ works is incorrect.

Comment: What's up with the downvotes.

Comment: Stackexchange just being stackexchange

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that your algebra regarding how min works is incorrect. In particular, since you had a square that you're trying to remove, the intermediate step that you omitted was $-\min(\cdots)\lt \mathfrak {Re}(y)\lt \min(\cdots)$, then when you take the minus sign inside the brackets you should switch the min to a max, instead of what you've done which is leave it alone. Why should you do this? Well, it's a consequence of the fact that you switch $\lt$ and $\gt$ when multiplying a statement by $-1$. So taking the negative of the smaller of a pair of numbers corresponds to taking the larger of the negatives.

Comment: I realize however there is still an issue on the right side of the inequality. Using your answer, what I should get to is that: $\text{max}\{2, -5+2\mathfrak{Re}(x)\}<\mathfrak{Re}(y)<\text{min}\{2\mathfrak{Re}(x)-2, 5\}$. For any values of $\mathfrak{Re}(x)$ (between 2 and 5), the left side always reduces to 2 however the right side can ALSO reduce to 2, which is a problem meaning there is still an error somewhere.

Comment: That's not a problem because we just get better bounds - concretely if $\mathfrak {Re}(x)=2.1$ then we get that $2\lt \mathfrak {Re}(y)\lt2.2$. Which is more than enough, since what we want is $2\lt \mathfrak {Re}(y)\lt5$ and $2.2\lt5$. Note also that since $\mathfrak {Re}(x)$ can't actually be 2 we don't need to worry about that edge case implying that $2\lt2$, because the edge case doesn't happen. Finally note that we get the same effect on the left side of the inequality when $\mathfrak {Re}(x)\gt3.5$.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach:

Sufficient to prove that every element in the set is an interior point.

Let each complex number $~z~$ be represented by $~x + iy ~: ~x,y \in \Bbb{R},~$ so that $~x~$ is the real part of $~z.$

Given a complex number $~z_0,~$ such that $~2 < x_0 < 5,~$ let $~\displaystyle \delta = 
\min\left( ~\frac{x_0-2}{2}, ~\frac{5-x_0}{2} ~\right).~$

Suppose that $~z_1 = x_1 + iy_1~$ is in the neighborhood of radius $~\delta~$ around the point $~z_0.$

Then,

$$|x_1 - x_0| \leq \delta \implies - \delta \leq x_1 - x_0 \leq \delta \implies $$

$$x_0 - \delta \leq x_1 \leq x_0 + \delta \implies $$

$$x_0 - \frac{x_0 - 2}{2} \leq x_0 - \delta \leq x_1 \leq x_0 + \delta \leq x_0 + \frac{x_0 - 2}{2} \implies $$

$$2 < \frac{x_0 + 2}{2} \leq x_1.$$

Similarly,

$$x_0 - \delta \leq x_1 \leq x_0 + \delta \implies $$

$$x_0 - \frac{5 - x_0}{2} \leq x_0 - \delta \leq x_1 \leq x_0 + \delta 
\leq x_0 + \frac{5 - x_0}{2} \implies $$

$$x_1 \leq \frac{5 + x_0}{2} < 5.$$

**Edit**
See also the comment of pts immediately following this answer.

Comment: A few closing sentences can be added: Since we have $2<x_1<5$, $z_1$ is in the set. Thus any point within the neighborhood of radius $\delta$ of $z_0$ is in the set. This is true for any $z_0$ in the set. Thus the set is open.

Comment: @pts  +1 : Nice comment, which I agree with.  I added a corresponding trailing reference to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This set is just $p_2^{-1}[(2, 5)]$, where $p_2: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the projection on the second coordinate, so it's the inverse image of an open set by a continuous function, hence open (if you need/want/are going to prove anything, prove that projections are continuous; it's *much* better than messy calculations)

Comment: ac15, thank you for your response. I see how that is an easier approach. Unfortunately, I am trying to do this without the use of functions, specifically because they haven’t been defined in the book until a later chapter. Also, it bugs me that this approach doesn’t seem to work when it clearly should. Any suggestions regarding this?